# Set custom keyboard mapping

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Xubuntu. I'm not sure if this applies to other flavors of Ubuntu as well.

I used to set a custom keyboard mapping in `.XCompose`.

```
# Include systemwide config
include "%L"

<Multi_key> <colon> <3>                 : ""       # : 3   Panda
<Multi_key> <8> <period>                : "☃"       # 8 .   Snowman
<Multi_key> <equal> <parenright>        : ""       # = ) grinning cat face with smiling eyes
<Multi_key> <equal> <minus>             : ""       # = - cat face with tears of joy
<Multi_key> <equal> <D>                 : ""       # = D smiling cat face with open mouth
<Multi_key> <equal> <3>                 : ""       # = 3 smiling cat face with heart-shaped eyes
<Multi_key> <equal> <slash>             : ""       # = / cat face with wry smile
<Multi_key> <bar> <3>                   : ""       # | 3 kissing cat face with closed eyes
<Multi_key> <greater> <equal>           : ""       # > 3 pouting cat face
<Multi_key> <equal> <parenleft>         : ""       # = ( crying cat face
<Multi_key> <D> <equal>                 : ""       # D = weary cat face
<Multi_key> <p> <p>                     : ""       # p p pumpkin
```

This can be loaded by setting `xim` as input method using `im-config`. This still works, but not always. It doesn't work in [Atom](https://atom.io/) and as of `<insert the breaking Ubuntu version here>` it makes [synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) crash entirely.

I've also read at some point that `.XModmap` is deprecated, but I don't recall the exact sources.

All sources on what to configure exactly are a big vague. The only thing I got  to work is using `.XModmap`.

What is the way to go nowadays (Xubuntu 16.04 / 16.10) to set custom key mappings? Preferably system-wide.

Comment: As regards not always works, please see [bug #1573755](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755). Cleaning up in `$HOME` might help.